# Django: prefetch_related from different db without relation

Tags: django

Consider the following models:

```
# in database "pizzas"
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

# in database "toppings"
class Topping(models.Model):
    metadata = models.JSONField()
```

In the pizzas table in the pizzas database I have

```
id | name
 1 | BBQ Meat Lover
 2 | Pepperoni
```

In the toppings table in the toppings database I have

```
id | metadata
 1 | {"pizza":{"id": 1}}
 2 | {"pizza":{"id": 2}}
```

Now I've worked out how I could move the pizza ID up a level in the queryset by doing:

```
Topping.objects.annotate(pizza_id=KeyTextTransform("id", "pizza"))
```

Now how would I be able to select the related pizzas using the `pizza.id` ?

Ideally, I would like to be able to access the queryset like so:

```
for topping in queryset:
    print(topping.pizza.name)
```